# mix static and dynamic linking

Tags: go, linker, static-linking

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69774444/7607408 says:

> You should be able to remove the gc_linkopts options from the build.
> Statically linking glibc is not really supported, and may be causing
> problems.
>
> If you have other cgo libraries you need to link statically, you will
> need to provide the linker flags for those libraries specifically.

Which suggests that it's possible to only statically link a specific library. However I can't find any information on how to do that with the go command line?

Comment: This isn't anything that the Go cli can provide, it's up to the external linker you are using, i.e. `ld` and `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809794/use-both-static-and-dynamically-linked-libraries-in-gcc